# Shell, suppress files with numbers in its name

Tags: shell

I am trying to script a procedure but I am really stuck now.

In a folder, I have some files, let say:

```
000001.dat
000002.dat
000003.dat
000004.dat
000005.dat
000006.dat
000007.dat
000008.dat
000009.dat
000010.dat
```

In a variable, I have `echo $num` > `000009`.
What I would like to do is to suppress the intermediate file like:
`rm -f {000001..${num}}*`, but it doesn't work...

If I use `rm -f {000001..000009}*`, it works! So I think it is a problem when reading the `num` variable.

Any helps? :)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using eval:

```
$ x=1;y=9
$ echo {$x..$y}
{1..9}
$ eval echo {$x..$y}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks, it well works :)
```rm `eval echo {$x..$y}` ```

Comment: Lucky, if it worked for you. Handling of leading zeros in brace expansion seems to be different depending on the shell. For `x=000001;y=000009; eval echo {$x..$y}` In bash i get `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, ksh does no expansion, if more than one leading 0 is used. In ksh it would be able to use `echo {1..9%06d}.dat`